# Doctrine - No mapping found for field x on class in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am currently getting an error stating `No mapping found for field 'activeJob' on class 'App\\Entity\\Entry`

I have a mapped property called `$jobs` that has a OneToMany relationship with the `Job` entity. I have then created a new 'calculated' property that uses the $jobs collection and returns a single Job with a OneToOne relation. This property is unmapped in the database, and the getter determines which job to return.

```
#[Groups(['submission:read'])]
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'submission', targetEntity: Job::class, fetch: 'EXTRA_LAZY')]
private Collection $jobs;

#[Groups(['submission:read'])]
private ?Job $activeJob = null;
```

If I add `#[ORM\OneToOne(mappedBy: 'submission', targetEntity: Job::class)]` to the `$activeJob` property, this technically does work but it still throws an invalid entity in the profiler.

`The mappings App\Entity\Submission#activeJob and App\Entity\Job#submission are inconsistent with each other.`

What do I need to do?

**Edit:**

Added the inverse side of the relationship on the `Job` entity, mapping to the `$jobs` property.

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(fetch: 'EXTRA_LAZY', inversedBy: 'jobs')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private ?Submission $submission = null;
```

--

Running PHP 8.1, Symfony 6.3, Doctrine ORM 2.15.x

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason why $activeJob would even be visible to Doctrine without an ORM attribute.  Maybe update you question showing the annotation for Job::submission.  Setting inversedBy attribute to activeJob (instead of jobs) might cause the error.  Just guessing.

Comment: @Cerad no problem - I've updated my question showing the inverse side of the relationship and the mapping back to the submission entity.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where does your `Groups` attribute come from?

Comment: @Cerad yeah, probably should have omitted these from the question. The `#[Groups]` are from the Api Platform framework that is also in use. They define the normalization and denormalization groups during the serialization process. It wouldn't be a cause for this issue.

Comment: Hmmm.  The api platform works closely with Doctrine.  Can't help but wonder of there is a link there.  I suppose you have tried removing it?  I know that would probably impact your query but might be worth investigating.

Comment: @Cerad unfortunately, I have tried this as well as removing the `?Job` type definition, just to see. Although removing the group would make it a bit pointless to me, I did test without and had the same response. Could this be a bug perhaps?

Comment: A Doctrine bug seems unlikely.  Somewhere something is treating activeJob as a Doctrine property.  Have you tried grepping for activeJob?  Sometimes when I get really stuck I'll create a fresh project and try for a minimalist test case.

Comment: The error message is explicit, I think. Your `activeJob` field is not mapped with `#[ORM\OneToMany]`

Comment: @bechir Correct. It's not mapped at all, technically. But, without some form of ORM attribute, it throws the `no mapping found for activeJob`. Weirdly, it only actually throws when I call `getJobs()` rather than `getActiveJob()`. Calling `getActiveJob()` on its own in a request works as expected.